# PGFGantt group placement error in case of a milestone

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

If you execute the code below, you get not so nice output (see screenshot below).

How can I fix:

- The Group label/bar is **overwritting** the milestone. This is not what I want. How to move the group 1 line below the milestone?
- After the milestone is completed work on "Group" can be started, so I want a **line from the Milestone to the first task of the group ("Task 2")**. How to do this? As you can see I get a line from the end of the group to the beginning of the task. If this cannot be done, how can I get a line from milestone to begin of the group and begin of group the the first task?

Thanks

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfgantt}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{ganttchart}{1}{21}
    \gantttitle{2015}{9}\gantttitle{2016}{12} \\
    \gantttitlelist{4,...,12}{1}\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\ 
    \ganttbar{Task1}{3}{6} \\ 
    \ganttlinkedmilestone{MyMilestone}{6} 
    \ganttgroup{Group}{7}{19} \\
    \ganttbar{Task2}{7}{9} \\  
    \ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
    \end{ganttchart}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Gannt chart going wrong]

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{21}
\gantttitle{2015}{9}\gantttitle{2016}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{4,...,12}{1}\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
\ganttbar{Task1}{3}{6} \\
\ganttlinkedmilestone{MyMilestone}{6} \\
\ganttgroup{Group}{7}{19} \\
\ganttbar{Task2}{7}{9} \\
\ganttlink{elem1}{elem2}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or like this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{21}
\gantttitle{2015}{9}\gantttitle{2016}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{4,...,12}{1}\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
\ganttbar{Task1}{3}{6} \\
\ganttlinkedmilestone{MyMilestone}{6} \\
\ganttgroup{Group}{7}{19} \\
\ganttbar{Task2}{7}{9} \\
\ganttlink[ link mid=.25,]{elem1}{elem3}    %%  link bulge=1.3 if needed
%\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]